# Make a div scroll when content exceeds available height

Tags: css

I'm trying to get my middle div `#content` to scroll when the height of its content exceeds the available height (as defined by the innerWidth - header height - footer height).

Instead, the div has a scrollbar that doesn't scroll, and the whole page has a scrollbar instead.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
#header {
 background-color: silver;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
}
#content {
 overflow: scroll;
}
#footer {
 background-color: silver;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="content">
a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>q<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>q<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>q<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: Fixed element do not go into flow with relatives so your content is acctualy the page and it's only beneath the div, let me show you in the answer :)

Comment: add height: ???px to your #content and remove position: fixed from #footer it's not that necessery

Comment: @Jung I don't know what the height is because this depends on the browser.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Check out my answer: you can dynamically set it using `calc()`

Comment: @DanielWilliams Lambda Ninja's calc() method should help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `#content` a fixed height, and it will work. Right now it doesn't work because `#content` has a dynamic height, and instead of scrolling when overflowing (because it will never overflow), it will expand.

See the snippet below.

(I set `body` and `html` to `height: 100%` and the height of `#content` to `calc(100% - 200px)` to fill up all the space not filled up by the header or the footer).

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
 background-color: silver;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
}
#content {
 overflow: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
#footer {
 background-color: silver;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="content">
a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>q<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>q<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>q<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: I'd add a note for browser support for calc , but the answer addresses the issue nicely :) you should only use `overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll` so the scrollbar takes vertical position :)

Comment: Perfect. I did try `height: calc(100% - 200px);` to no effect. `body height: 100%;` is what I needed!

Comment: @MarkoMackic Yes, good thinking! But it should be `overflow: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;`

Comment: @DanielWilliams If this helped you, feel free to upvote and accept this answer to show the community it helped you!

Comment: @DanielWilliams and MarkoMackic: Also, I don't think you need `overflow-x:hidden` because text wraps by default, even with `overflow: scroll`, unless `white-space` is set to `nowrap`

Comment: @LambdaNinja I was getting a horizontal scrollbar even without wider content, so `overflow: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;` has achieved what I'm after :-)